# How to catch any Javascript exception in Clojurescript?

Tags: error-handling, interop, clojurescript, swallowed-exceptions

In my communication layer I have a need to be able to catch ANY javascript exception, log it down and proceed as I normally would do.
Current syntax for catching exceptions in Clojurescript dictates that I need to specify the type of the exception being caught.

I tried to use nil, js/Error, js/object in the catch form and it doesn't catch ANY javascript exception (which can have string as the type of the object).

I would appreciate any hints how this can be done natively in Clojurescript.

Comment: Hi Dima! Do you think my response fix your problem?

Answer (score 53):

I found another possible answer in David Nolen ["Light Table ClojureScript Tutorial"](https://github.com/swannodette/lt-cljs-tutorial)

```
;; Error Handling
;; ============================================================================

;; Error handling in ClojureScript is relatively straightforward and more or
;; less similar to what is offered in JavaScript.

;; You can construct an error like this.

(js/Error. "Oops")

;; You can throw an error like this.

(throw (js/Error. "Oops"))

;; You can catch an error like this.

(try
  (throw (js/Error. "Oops"))
  (catch js/Error e
    e))

;; JavaScript unfortunately allows you to throw anything. You can handle
;; this in ClojureScript with the following.

(try
  (throw (js/Error. "Oops"))
  (catch :default e
    e))
```

Comment: This is now the proper way to do it.

Comment: `:default` does not currently exist in "regular" (Java-based) Clojure, but there is a proposal to add it to that as well: http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-1293

Comment: `#?(:cljs :default :clj Throwable)` instead of `:default` will work for both clj and cljs, in a cljc file

Answer (score 6):

It looks like js/Object catches them all (tested on https://himera.herokuapp.com):

```
cljs.user> (try (throw (js/Error. "some error")) (catch js/Object e (str "Caught: " e)))
"Caught: Error: some error"
cljs.user> (try (throw "string error") (catch js/Object e (str "Caught: " e)))
"Caught: string error"
cljs.user> (try (js/eval "throw 'js error';") (catch js/Object e (str "Caught: " e)))
"Caught: js error"
```

One thing to watch out for is lazy sequences. If an error is thrown in a lazy sequence that part of the code might not be executed until after you've exited the try function. For example:

```
cljs.user> (try (map #(if (zero? %) (throw "some error")) [1]))
(nil)
cljs.user> (try (map #(if (zero? %) (throw "some error")) [0]))
; script fails with "Uncaught some error"
```

In that last case, map creates a lazy sequence and the try function returns it. Then, when the repl tries to print the sequence to the console, it's evaluated and the error gets thrown outside of the try expression.

Comment: you can catch them with `:default` too which is probably more idiomatic

Answer (score 4):

I think I've just found the solution in this link 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/QHaTwjD4zzU

I copy the contents here: 
This solution was published by  Herwig Hochleitner

> try in clojurescript is actually a macro that uses the builtin try*
>   and adds type dispatch. So to catch everything, just use (try* ...
>   (catch e ...)). This maps directly to javascript's try.

And here is my implementation working now:

```
(defn is-dir? [the_dir]
  (try*
    (if-let [stat (.statSync fs the_dir )]
      (.isDirectory stat)
      false)
    (catch  e 
      (println "catching all exceptions, include js/exeptions")
      false
      )
    )
  )
```

I hope it helps you
Juan

Comment: try* is now deprecated. Use the :default as in your other answer